# Bubble notifications above current page route in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

I'd like to use a NotificationListener in flutter to catch a notification from a widget below the current one in the widget tree. However, the widget that fires the notification isn't in the same route, but in a route below the one of the NotificationListener (because of the use of Navigator.push, i.e. the NotificationListener isn't present in the current widget tree, but is rather obscured by the current page route). Is there a way to bubble the notification above the current route?

Comment: `Notification.dispatch()` takes `BuildContext` so most likely you need to provide the one from the route below

Comment: @pskink I tried to use dispatch(Navigator.of(context).context) but it didn't work

Comment: `Navigator.of(context).context` is not a context of your previous route